# XSL: Construct an Array from a Delimited String

Tags: arrays, xslt

I have a string in which data is separated by a delimiter like `"|"` and is present in a variable.
I would like to create an array in the XSL by dividing the above string based on the delimiter and would like to access the same in the in a for loop.

Please help me in this regard.
Please also let me know if anyone need any more information.

String is `"Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4"` and would like to get a variable `TEMP` which would be an array of data from the string and would like to access as `TEMP[index]`.

I have tried to use the tokenize function after the inputs from the forum members to get the values from the string but was not successful. I am not getting the string values in the loop.

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" select="str:tokenize(normalize-space(' Test1$,$Test2$,$Test3$,$Test4 '),'$,$')"/>
<xsl:for-each xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" select="str:split(normalize-space(' 1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6 '),'$,$')">
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$temp[$index]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Regards,
Lakshman

Comment: FYI, XSLT doesn't have arrays. In XSLT 1.0 / EXSLT, the `tokenize()` extension function returns a *node set* or a *result tree fragment* (which can be turned into a node set using another extension function, `node-set()`). This node set can be accessed by index as you specified, because the elements representing tokens map one-to-one to children of a parent node, in order.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, but what the OP wants can be modeled in XSLT 1.0 by a node-set containing elements each of which contains a token -- see my answer.

Comment: @Dimitre: yeah, I was alluding to that in my comment. There were already good answers posted describing how to do that when I wrote my comment. I just wanted to add a bit about 'array' terminology.

Answer (score 16):

> String is `"Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4"` and would like to get a variable
>   `TEMP` which would be an array of data from the string and would like
>   to access as `TEMP[index]`.

+1 for a good question.

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfTokens">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vTokens" select=
   "ext:node-set($vrtfTokens)/*"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select=
   "document('')//node()[not(position() > count($vTokens))]
   ">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vTokens[$vPos+0]"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
   <xsl:variable name="vToken" select=
    "substring-before(concat($pText,'|'), '|')"/>
   <s><xsl:value-of select="$vToken"/></s>

   <xsl:call-template name="split">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
    "substring-after($pText, '|')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4</t>
```

creates a variable `vTokens` that contains elements named `s`, each of which has as its only text child a token from the '|'-delimited string `"Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4"`.

Then the transformation outputs each of these `s` elements using an "index".

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<s>Test1</s>
<s>Test2</s>
<s>Test3</s>
<s>Test4</s>
```

In case we want just the tokens (strings) themselves, we'd use:

```
string($vTokens[someIndex])
```

Comment: @Bugude: You are welcome. Probably you need to be aware that saying "Thank you" at SO is officially done by accepting the best answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it -- and you can do this now) and by upvoting any answer (by clicking its ^ arrow -- something you'll be allowed to do when you have accumulated 50 points yourself).

Answer (score 10):

It won't be an array but a sequence, and you must have a XSLT 2.0 processor. You can use the `tokenize()` function :

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize('Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4','\|')"/>
```

You can also pass a string variable as first argument of tokenize.

Then you use :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$temp[$index]"/>
```

EDIT : achieve this in xslt 1.0 is not possible unless you use some extension.

Comment: Thank you Vincent...This help and worked when I am using individually and using XSLT 2.0. Unfortunately, the application is using old version, is there anyway that this can be done in version 1.0

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not in the xpath 1.0 standard and you have to use an exslt extension as Martin pointed out.

Comment: @VincentBiragnet: Your statement that one *must* use an XSLT 2.0 processor in order to implement the OP's requirements, is not true. See my XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 3):

That task is called tokenizing, in XSLT 2.0 you can use `tokenize('Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4', '\|')`, with XSLT 1.0 you can use an extension like http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
I have tried to use the tokenize function to get the values from the string but was not successful.
I am not getting the string values in the loop.

<xsl:variable name="temp" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" select="str:tokenize(normalize-space(' Test1$,$Test2$,$Test3$,$Test4 '),'$,$')"/>
<xsl:for-each xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" select="str:split(normalize-space(' 1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6 '),'$,$')">
 <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="$temp[$index]"/>
</xsl:for-each>

Comment: The above code that is mentioned is used to populate a table in a workbook. The values that are obtained in the for loop will go in each row of a table in the workbook (Excel)

Answer (score 3):

I try this, I modified the "Dimitre Novatchev" code, and works for me: (please excuse me for my English)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="_keywords">
            <xsl:call-template name="split-to-values">
                <xsl:with-param name="_text" select="Keywords-comma-separated"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($_keywords)/value">
            <xsl:variable name="_keyword" select="."/>
            <!-- ANY CODE -->
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" name="split-to-values">
    <xsl:param name="_text"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($_text)">
        <xsl:variable name="_value" select="substring-before($_text, ',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="_next" select="substring-after($_text, ',')"/>
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="$_value"/>
        </value>

        <xsl:call-template name="split-to-values">
            <xsl:with-param name="_text" select="$_next"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I hope it helps you

@Bugude ask

> I have a string in which data is separated by a delimiter like "|" and
>   is present in a variable. I would like to create an array in the XSL
>   by dividing the above string based on the delimiter and would like to
>   access the same in the in a for loop

Then the string may be:  "alfa,beta,gama,delta"

The delimiter is presented in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="_delimiter">,</xsl:variable>
```

I modified the template as:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="split-to-values">
    <xsl:param name="_text"/>
    <xsl:param name="_delimiter"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($_text)">
        <xsl:variable name="_value" select="substring-before($_text, $_delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="_next" select="substring-after($_text, $_delimiter)"/>
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="$_value"/>
        </value>

        <xsl:call-template name="split-to-values">
            <xsl:with-param name="_text" select="$_next"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="_delimiter" select="$_delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And we can access to the nodes as similar an array with a for

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
        <!-- _keyword as set a node -->
        <xsl:variable name="_keywords">
            <xsl:call-template name="split-to-values">
                <xsl:with-param name="_text" select="'alfa,beta,gama,delta'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="_delimiter" select="$_delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($_keywords)/value">
            <xsl:variable name="_keyword" select="."/>
            <!-- ANY CODE -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$_keyword"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.